# Qlabel with image as the background overlaps other Qlabels

Tags: qt, qlabel

I have a Qlabel with image as rich text and some other Qlabels on top of that as in the picture:[image]

although I sent the Qlabel with image to back but when I run they appear as follows: [image]

is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Make the text labels children of the label containing the fade. Also I can not see any layouts. Did you use layouts? You could also put the fade on the widget by implementing its `paintEvent()`. All other widgets will be displayed on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

Try right clicking the image label and clicking the send-to-back option. That might work. That should send the QLabel behind the other elements even though they appear as though they are already in front.